# How to get unique values excluding values from 1 of 2 tables

Tags: sql, mariadb

I need to get unique values from 2 tables, but exclude the values from the second table. I mean, I need all the values from the first table that are **not** in the second table and are greater than 9. *The tables look like:*

```
Table Gr:           Table Ak:
Idgr | TextGr       Idak | Grid | TextAk
1    | Aa           1    | 11   | R
11   | Bb           2    | 14   | P
12   | Cc           3    | 16   | P
13   | Dd           4    | 13   | P
14   | Ee           
15   | Ff           
16   | Gg           
17   | Hh           
18   | Ii
```

`Grid` on table Ak is the same ID from `Idgr` on table Gr.
I need to get result like this:

```
Results:
Idgr | TextGr
12   | Cc
15   | Ff
17   | Hh
18   | Ii
```

I tried with LEFT OUTER JOIN, but I get almost all values from table Gr. Check out [SQLfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/802b1b/4)

Answer (score 1):

You want to test for equality in the `on` and then use a `where` to get the ones that don't match.  So, I think you want:

```
select Idgr, TextGr
from Gr left outer join
     Ak
     on gr.idgr = ak.gid
where gr.idgr > 9 and ak.Idak is null;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/802b1b/10) is the SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the keyword EXCEPT.

```
(SELECT Idgr AS Idgr FROM Gr WHERE Idgr > 9)
EXCEPT
(SELECT Grid AS Idgr FROM Ak);
```

This will provide a list of all values from Gr then subtract the values that match from Ak. In Mariadb it's called EXCEPT in other SQL variants it is often called MINUS.